# Getting site-main and widget-area to sit in the centre of the page

Tags: css, wordpress, layout

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

The FB widget was to big for my widget area so I used the below code to adjust the width of the two sections of my page.

```
 #primary.content-area {float: left;width: 70%;}
    #primary.content-area .site-main{width:100%;}
    .widget-area{float:right;width:30%;}
```

I also modified the Penscratch theme so the custom header and navigation menu extend across the whole page.

An unintended consequence of all these changes is now when I zoom out on my website there is a massive imbalance of white space on both sides of my site.

I want to try and center align the content - area and widget - area.

I have not tried any possible solutions because I have been unable to find any information on Google to point me vaguely in the right direction. All the information I found on Google was related to other themes or just related to centering individual pictures, text and headers.

Update -

I tried one suggestion below. Now my code looks like this -

```
<div class="full-screen-template">
#primary.content-area {float: left;width: 70%;}
#primary.content-area .site-main{width:100%;}
.widget-area{float:right;width:30%;}
</div>

#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="mobile-template">
#primary.content-area {float: left;width: 100%;}
.widget-area{float:right;width:100%;}
</div>
```

Unfortunately it has not seemed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to center align the content and widget area:

```
#page {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the reason it doesn't work is that you have HTML code inside .css file:

```
<div class="full-screen-template">
....
</div>
```

This probably stops the browser to go any further, so it never reaches the  `#page` line.

I'm not sure what you try to achieve with HTML in css file but try to remove it to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried your code but it did not seem to work. Please see the bottom of my original question. I have updated it.

Comment: Updated the answer.